# C# Unity: Cannot convert method group 'GetComponent' to non-delegate type ' Rigidbody2D'

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to C#/C++(Sorry if the mistake in the code is obvious.)

I am using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s4ObxcdXoFE) (1:27:47 mark) and have run into an error. I tried to fix this code by looking through the web for solutions for other people who had similar problems. When I first got this code, the error was:

`UnityEngine.Component' does not contain a definition for 'velocity' and no extension method 'velocity' of type 'UnityEngine.Component' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?'`

After I applied some fixes, this is what the code looks like now:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

//This scrits makes the character move when the screen is pressed and 
handles the jump
public class CharacterFinal : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool jump = false;               // Condition for whether the player should jump.    
public float jumpForce = 10.0f;         // Amount of force added when the player jumps.
private bool grounded = false;          // Whether or not the player is grounded.
public int movementSpeed = 10;          // The vertical speed of the movement
private Animator anim;                  // The animator that controls the characters animations
//Declare rigid2D
Rigidbody2D rigid2D;
// Use this for initialization

void Awake()
{
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>();

    //Initialize rigid2D
    rigid2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>;
}


//This method is called when the character collides with a collider (could be a platform).
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D hit)
{
    grounded = true;
    print ("isground");
}

//The update method is called many times per seconds
void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {       
        // If the jump button is pressed and the player is grounded and the character is running forward then the player should jump.
        if(grounded == true)                        
        {
            jump = true;
            grounded = false;
            //We trigger the Jump animation state
            anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
        }

    }

}




//Since we are using physics for movement, we use the FixedUpdate method
void FixedUpdate ()
{

    //if died that 
    rigid2D.velocity = new Vector2(movementSpeed, rigid2D.velocity.y );
    //else
    //moving


    // If jump is set to true we add a quick force impulse for the jump
    if(jump == true)
    {
        // Add a vertical force to the player.
        rigid2D.AddForce(new Vector2(0f, jumpForce),ForceMode2D.Impulse);

        // We set the variable to false again to avoid adding force constantly
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

}

The error it gives is this

```
Cannot convert method group 'GetComponent' to non-delegate type 
UnityEngine.Rigidbody2D'.
```

The error is on line 22

```
rigid2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply change

```
rigid2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>;
```

to

```
rigid2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
```

note the `()` at the end. The error said it could not convert "method group" - that's because it is a method, but you didn't CALL it properly.